# Not able to read the image path. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-imaging-library, argparse

I am working on predicting image labels of flowers. I am passing the path to the image as an argument by argparser. But I am getting the following error.

How do I fix this?

`python predict.py --input_img 'flowers/test/99/image_07833.jpg'`

```
checkpoint loaded
image path is ['flowers/test/99/image_07833.jpg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2481, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 40, in <module>
    top_probs, top_labels, top_flowers = utils.predict(image_path, model, cat_to_name, topk)
  File "/home/workspace/ImageClassifier/utils.py", line 249, in predict
    image = process_image(image_path)
  File "/home/workspace/ImageClassifier/utils.py", line 213, in process_image
    img = Image.open(image)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2483, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Your path is clearly a list, which I guess shouldn't be.

Comment: If you see image path is [...] is cause is a list, you can just re-asign your variable, file_path = file_path[0] (I invent variables cause you dont post code)

Answer (score 0):

You probably set `nargs=1` when adding the argument `input_img` to your argument parser. 
Something like:

```py
parser.add_argument('--input_img', type=open, nargs=1)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from
>   the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

Just remove `nargs`:

```py
parser.add_argument('--input_img', type=open)
```